# Foreword, Appendix headings formatting in poemscol

Tags: article, renewcommand, poemscol

I'm trying to change the font size, style and place a rule under two (2) sections in a poetry collection using **poemscol**.

My desired result is a centered title with a rule underneath the width of the text body block. It should 3mm below the title and 12mm between the body text.

The sections are called by the `\makeforeword` and `makeappendix` commands. The manual refers to `\forewordtitle` and `\appendixtitle`. To get my desired result, I've tried to modify both of these using `\renewcommand` without success.

My MWE calls the rule inline with the command, but this is a kludge as I can't seem to set the spacing between the title and the body text, or center the title.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{poemscol}
\changecontentsname{Contents}
\setcontentsleaders{\hfill}
\begin{document}
% frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\makeforeword{Editor's Note}\hrule\vspace{0.12cm}
Text of editor's note.\\
\lipsum
\putpoemcontents
\makepoemcontents
% mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\makeappendix{Appendix}\hrule\vspace{0.12cm}
Appendix here.\\
\lipsum
\end{document}
```